# Obstacle problem assumptions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $V=U_0=H^1_0(\Omega)$,  $L(v)=(f,v)$ for $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Let $\Psi\in H^1(\Omega)\cap C^0(\overline\Omega)$ and $\Psi|_\Gamma\leq0.$
Define $K=\{v\in H^1_0(\Omega):v\geq \Psi \text{ a.e. in }\Omega\}$ and $a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot \nabla v ~\mathrm{d} x$.

My query :

1. why such an assumption on $\Psi$ that $\Psi\leq 0$.
2. how to prove that set $K$ is non empty here.

Initially i thought that $0$ function will be there but that may not be true.

any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the equation being considered? $a(u,v)=L(v)$? Rather, what does $u$ have to do with anything?

Comment: $a(u,v-u)\geq L(v-u)$

Comment: I still don't totally understand the setup, then. Is it "find $u$ such that $a(u,v-u) \geq L(v-u)$ for all $v \in K$"?

Comment: yes
the setup is that only but existence of such a solution comes from Stampachia, my doubt is how come we can show that $K$ is non empty

Comment: Isn't $\Psi \in K$?

Comment: no
because $\Psi$ may not be equivalently $0$ on whole of boundary

Comment: Oh, I see, $C^0$ as in continuous, not vanishing on the boundary.

Comment: Is $\Omega$ such that the Dirichlet problem has solutions? If so, you could consider $\Delta w=0$ in $\Omega$ subject to $w(x)=-\Psi(x)$ on $\Gamma$, then by the minimum principle $w \geq 0$, now $w+\Psi \in K$, right? Obviously this is quite the brute force approach...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the domain $\Omega$ has the necessary geometric properties that the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation has classical solutions, one explanation for #2 that sort of explains #1 as well is to consider the solution $w$ to the Dirichlet problem with the boundary function $-\Psi$. Then $w+\Psi \in H^1_0$ is automatic. Because you assume $\Psi \leq 0$, you get by the minimum principle that $w \geq 0$, so in fact $w+\Psi \in K$. If you didn't assume $\Psi \leq 0$ then you wouldn't have $w \geq 0$ (but of course that doesn't mean that $K$ is necessarily empty, only that this construction breaks).

I'm not entirely sure this is useful in the setting of the underlying problem, because I'm not really acquainted with obstacle problems. But it seems to answer your specific questions here.